# List Songs in UITableViewController on iPhone? Works in Storyboard, NOT without it

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I am NOT using Storyboards.  I have a UITableViewController and I would like to display a list of songs from user's library.

This is my code so far:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    MPMediaQuery *songsQuery = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
    NSArray *songs = [songsQuery items];

    return [songs count];
}
```

But for this block, I do not know what to do.  [I found a tutorial for storyboards](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-an-ios-music-player-app-setup--pre-48839), but it is not valid here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    MPMediaQuery *songsQuery = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
    NSArray *songs = [songsQuery items];

    MPMediaItem *rowItem = [songs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [rowItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [rowItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];

    return cell;
}
```

This only works in Storyboard because I can click the cell in the storyboard and rename its identifier to 'Cell'.  In the .xib/nib file in my project, all I see is a view filled with country's names.  I cannot click a single cell, I can only edit the whole table.

My question is, what code must I put in - `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` in order to display this list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem you're encountering is that, when used in conjunction with a properly configured storyboard, `dequeueReusableCell...` will create a cell of the appropriate type if none is available to dequeue.

If you are using a standard UITableViewCell, you can use the following block to dequeue and/or create an appropriate cell:

```
static NSString*    reuseIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell*    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if(!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
}
```

If, on the other hand, you're loading your cells from a nib file, you can just add:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:nibName bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```

to your viewDidLoad.

Alternatively you can use `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` if you have a custom cell class that sets up it's own subviews.

Answer (score 2):

First off, check if the cell being dequeued is nil or not.

The next thing I can see a problem with is the fact that you aren't really loading anything in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Basically what this method does is dequeue some cell which has been marked for reuse in an attempt to save memory, and if you haven't set the proper `Restoration Identifier` in the Interface Builder, then there is no way to know which Nib you want initialized to use here.

What used to happen (or at least my understanding of it) is that in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you would have to check if the cell returned from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` was nil, and if so, you'd have to create the cell from scratch using something like this:

```
SomeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SomeCellNib" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

and this would ensure that if no cell was dequeued that you would load up a fresh one from scratch, although I believe that Apple actually changed how `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` works, and as long as you've registered the Identifier, it will create a new cell for you.

For this reason I'm not sure what the problem is if you've set the Identifier properly, and all I can suggest is to try and manually load the cell.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention where Restoration Identifiers can be set. The Restoration Identifer field is in the **Identity** tab, or the third tab in the Interface Builder:

[image: Location of Restoration Identifier in Interface Builder]

Comment: I don't see a Reuse Identifier option.  This is my nib - http://i.imgur.com/bpnBwp7.png :S Thanks for the info by the way, but I'm not sure what to do

Comment: The Restoration Identifer field is in the **Identity** tab, or the third tab in the Interface Builder: [pic here](http://i.imgur.com/HXbWnWw.png)

Comment: Thanks, but now I get an error in my app delegate.m file on line -     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; - that says Thread 1: SIGABRT - error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:' :S Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: What exactly did you change? This is telling you that you aren't actually returning a non-nil cell from that method.

Comment: Whoops, I did something a bit silly.  But now I've done everything you said - I put the Restoration ID as 'Cell' but I still get the same error - *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard' on the same line as my original question :S

Comment: Hi Nik, I'd like to thank you for your time and help, the solution below worked.  I really appreciate your help! :)

Comment: Cool! glad I could get you rolling

Answer (score 1):

To create a prototype cell inside a .nib, drag a `UITableCellView` out from the right sidebar. From there you can create your cell prototype, as well as set the cell reuse identifier.

Comment: How do I link this to the UITableView?  I can only drag the Table View Cell beside the UITableView and there is no Reuse Identifier field for it :S

Comment: As long as the cell is in the file, I believe it should be good to go. The reuse idenifier might under a different name in the .xib editor, but it should be there.

Comment: Ah I see the Reuse Identifier field now.  It loads with a blank table in my iOS simulator but when it runs on my iPhone, I get this error - NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard - and I'm not using a storyboard :S

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your help, the solution from David works.  It's strange because I added a new Cell to the nib file but it didn't work.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: I ran into this the other day. I'm guessing you forgot to register the cell for the reuse identifier? That would explain "must register a nib or a class for the identifier." I generally include all my cell registration in the viewDidLoad or initialization code.